# How to pass a php variable from hidden input value to a php script?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this form INSIDE a table :

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['first_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
        <td>
            <form action="send_notification.php" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="request">
            </form>
       </td>
```

Next to each row I have a button called "request" if I click on it I want 
to pass the php variable `$row['first_name']` to another PHP script .

How can I do that? 
I tried to do this in the php file `send_notification.php` :

```
<?php
session_start();
require("connect.php");

$id=$_GET['first_name'];

echo $id;
?>
```

But it gave me this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: first_name in path/send_notification.php on line 5

UPDATE ONE:

I change `$_GET['first_name']` to `$_POST['id']` , the output gave no error but it was a blank page. Should't it echo the $id?

Comment: `$id=$_GET['id'];` ?

Comment: You form is set to `POST` not `GET`

Comment: I grabbed it by the value, I did try what you just suggested and it gave me the same error, but instead of `first_name` undefined, I had `id` undefined

Comment: WillParky I did change it to $_POST, unfortunately send_notification.php outputted nothing. It's supposed to output the name

Comment: Too much wrong here, the variable name, the form's method and on top of that you are using php tags to `echo` inside an `echo` statement.

Comment: i was just wondering that too @jeroen, it seems so wrong to me i dont even know how it doesn't just send a syntax error right now

Comment: Y'all, what I posted is obviously an EXCERPT from my whole code . Unless you want a 200 line code to read through ,I'll be glad to send them to you by email . The table is working perfectly and the tags are correctly placed.

Comment: Yes, and the value of your name / id starts with a `<` so it is interpreted as an html tag and that is why you don't see anything when using `$_POST`...

Answer (score 0):

You are referring the wrong variable name.

When sending data via POST/GET, the `name` attribute will be considered as the variable name.

Also your form method is set to POST and you are checking the `$_GET` array.

Try fetching the value as mentioned below.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

**Changed code**

```
<?php
session_start();
require("connect.php");

$id = $_POST['id'];

echo $id;

?>
```

Comment: gave me a blank page instead of echoing the first name

Comment: try echoing the `$id` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="send_notification.php" method="POST">
```

here you specified that you want the value passed with POST

```
 $id=$_GET['first_name'];
```

and here you just ask it to be in the GET superglobal, it should be pretty obvious now, use $_POST, also, the name of your hidden input is id, and you ask for first name

but i was just wondering, the td on line 5 in your php isn't missing an echo or a closing php tag ? thats a strange way to do things, it seems you are mixing php echos with html containing php tags

Comment: The code I posted is an excerpt from the whole code. The table is working perfectly and so is the button with the closing tags correctly placed . though not in the scope of the code

Comment: @momo12321 yes but in the way you posted, we cannot see if the problem comes from two places at the times, so i was just adding that in case ;), I assume the second part of your php is in your html, so just add a ?> tag or put your 2 parts in separates boxes so we can know next time (this wasn't a problem this time as the issue was pretty simple)

Answer (score 0):

Change your hidden input name replace id to first_name.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";

 echo "<td>".$row['first_name'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
     <td>
                    <form action="send_notification.php" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="request">
                    </form>
                </td>
```

Comment: You should have read the comments before posting this answer. This specific problem has already been addressed various times but it does not solve the OP's problem.